# Extending momentjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, momentjs

I'm trying extend Moment.js using another plugin ( https://github.com/leonardosantos/momentjs-business ), but I got the following error:

**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Here my code:

```
(function () 
{
    var moment = (typeof require !== "undefined" && require !== null) && !require.amd ? require("moment") : this.moment;

    var originalAddMethod       = moment.fn.add;
    var originalSubtractMethod  = moment.fn.subtract;
    var originalDiffMethod      = moment.fn.diff;

    moment.fn.add = function ( number , string )
    {
        return string === 'business days' ? moment.fn.businessAdd( number , string ) : originalAddMethod.apply( this , arguments );
    }

}).call( this );
```

What is Wrong? What I Do?

Comment: You should check your console in browser and see which line exactly is producing the error. It seems your call stacksize limit is reached.

Comment: Haven't dug deeply into your code, but that extension calls .add. Meanwhile, you are overwriting .add. Suspect you should evaluate if this is the issue.

Comment: You find the problem Maggie! :D

But any advise to make it work?! Maybe I'll need fork the original code and instead call add I'll call originalAddMethod?

Comment: @YuriWallace why do you need to overwrite the .add method at all? Just use a function of a different name. I would not generally recommend maintaining a divergent fork of any open source project as you then have to come up with your own process for incorporating the source into your build, and you're responsible for merging bug fixes on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into one problem I saw a some ago with the same error, with Date prototype.

The quick fix that worked for me (not with *moment.js*, but *now.js* though), was this:

```
 if(Date.prototype._toString==undefined) { Date.prototype._toString=Date.prototype.toString; }
```

Not perfect, but at least it gets you started.

Comment: I found the problem... Inside businessAdd function, Add is called to, because this I got the stack problem. I fall in recursive problem. see the code:

https://github.com/leonardosantos/momentjs-business/blob/master/momentjs-business.js#L38


Any advise for  this problem? :D